# How to use Select query with MAX Date?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get latest Date from Database.But getting query error on `'Reservation.EntryDate'`

```
Select Rooms.RoomTitle,Rooms.IsReserved,Reservation.CheckInTime,Reservation.CheckOutTime
From Reservation,Rooms 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Reservation.RoomID, MAX(Reservation.EntryDate) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM Reservation
    GROUP BY Reservation.RoomID) groupedtt 
ON Rooms.RoomID = groupedtt.RoomID 
AND Reservation.EntryDate = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Multi Part Identifier Reservation.EntryDate not found

Comment: I think u havent specified any join for Reservation and rooms" from reservation,rooms inner join"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax

```
Select ro.RoomTitle, 
       ro.IsReserved, 
       res.CheckInTime, 
       res.CheckOutTime
From Reservation res
join Rooms ro ON ro.RoomID = res.RoomID
join
(
    SELECT RoomID, MAX(EntryDate) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM Reservation
    GROUP BY RoomID
) groupedtt ON ro.RoomID = groupedtt.RoomID 
           AND res.EntryDate = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Comment: Do you have these columns in your tables?

Comment: yes I do I have those table and names are also same

Comment: Try aliasing as I did

Comment: that works but can you also tell me how to use Distinct on Room ID of Reservation

Comment: That realy depends on what you try to do. You need to group probably. Ask another question, add example data and exptected output. That makes it easier to help you.